# pdf of inverted random variable

Tags: derivatives, random-variables

Suppose i have an uniform distributed random variable $X$ on $[5,30]$. I would like to find pmf of $Y = \frac{1}{X}.$

\begin{align*}
Y =& \frac{1}{X}\\
dY =& -\frac{1}{X^2}dX\\
dY =& -Y^2dX\\
-\frac{1}{Y^2}dY =& dX\\
\end{align*}

I believe that
$$f_{X}(x) = \frac{1}{25}dX$$
so
$$f_{Y}(y) = -\frac{1}{25}\frac{1}{Y^2}dY$$
But lecture notes give me answer without minus sign. Where i made a mistake?

Can it be because we kinda swap range borders because of division and how to express it formally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{25}$$
$$f_Y(y)=f_X(x)\bigg|\frac{dX}{dY}\bigg|=\frac{1}{25}\frac{1}{y^2}$$

Comment: You mean we need to use absolute value?

Comment: Yes, the transformation formula has absolute value.